# Type reference cannot refer to container

Tags: typescript

So I have two interfaces and a class:

```
 import IUpdate = require('IUpdate');
 import ITransformer = require('ITransformer');  //Has no trouble with ITransformer

 interface IRecognizer 
 {
     startRecognize(transformerToTell: ITransformer):void;

 }

 export = Recognizer;
```

and

```
import IUpdateLoc = require('IUpdateLoc');

interface ITransformer
{
    locationUpdate(update: IUpdateLoc):void;    

}

export = ITransformer;
```

but

```
import ITransformer = require('ITransformer');
import IRecognizer = require('IRecognizer');

import IUpdateLoc = require('IUpdateLoc');

class RealUpdate implements IRecognizer 
{
   startRecognize(trans: ITransformer):void{

   }

}

export = RealUpdate;
```

I am getting "Type reference cannot refer to container 'ITransformer' from my RealUpdate class.  I don't understand why it is okay to IRecognizer but not in RealUpdate?

probably not relevant:
module type is commonjs
I am working with Typescript using Eclipse using the https://bitbucket.org/axmor/typecs/wiki/Home plugin.

Comment: Which version of the compiler are you using? This looks like a bug that got fixed in a newer release (1.0 or later)

Comment: I have 1.1.0-1 (AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript) installed on my system but I'm not sure if the plugin for eclipse is using it.  They only mention needing Required software: Java 7, Eclipse Kepler 4.3 or higher, Node.js. So I'm thinking it is probably not using the compiler I have installed.

Comment: I think the plugin maybe using TS_1.0.  Based on eclipse\plugins\com.axmor.eclipse.typescript.core_2.0.0.201409230908\lib\bridge\ts_1.0\lib.d.ts

Comment: I configured typescript in Webstorm which shows that is is using typescript from AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript and this compiles fine there.  So I guess the issue is with the plugin.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/axmor/typecs/issue/19/typescript-compiler wrote an issues against the plugin.

Comment: Window->Preferences->Typescript shows the I am using 1.0.1 version of the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypEcsPlugin Issue][1](https://bitbucket.org/axmor/typecs/issue/19/typescript-compiler#comment-13151481)

According to the authors of the plugin I am using they are working on supporting a newer version of the compiler.  Since this compile issues doesn't seem to be an issue when I use [webstorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm) I believe the issue must be that this older typescript compiler.